# How to Extrapolate information by date in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have this object Date  in this format : `2014-05-20 18:17:26.337`

I try to do this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(myDate); 
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int dayOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int Month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

But the information are wrong..

How I can resolve it?

Comment: What you got?        .

Comment: the result of dayOfMonth is not correct. It returns 20

Comment: it is correct `2014-05-20`, `20` is the dayofMonth. What are you expecting ?

Comment: Ops sorry... but dayOfWeek = 3, Month = 4...they should be:dayOfWeek = 2 and Month =5 or not?

Comment: share full code and what are you getting

Comment: Iirc, some values are null-based, some aren't. This should be somewhere in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From java doc:

> Blockquote
>
> int java.util.Calendar.MONTH = 2 [0x2]
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is **JANUARY which is 0;** the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.
>
> See Also: JANUARY FEBRUARY MARCH APRIL MAY JUNE JULY AUGUST SEPTEMBER
>   OCTOBER NOVEMBER DECEMBER UNDECIMBER

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected value, please read the javadoc carefully: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

For Month:

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

For day of week:

> public static final int DAY_OF_WEEK
>   Field number for get and set indicating the day of the week. This field takes values SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read `Java` [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) first

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.

So you will get `month` as `4`

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```